# PHP export excel(codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

i want the export table from a webpage to Excel by using PHPExcel library in codeigniter.

When i click the export button it downloads a file with .xls extension but full off the errors. Here some of the errors image;

http://prntscr.com/qfpn1w

http://prntscr.com/qfpmlr

And here is my action function in controller ;

```
   function action()
    {
     $this->load->model("excel_export_model");
     $this->load->library("excel");
     $object = new PHPExcel();

     $object->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

     $table_columns = array("Name", "Address", "Gender", "Age");

     $column = 0;

     foreach($table_columns as $field)
     {
      $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 1, $field);
      $column++;
     }

     $employee_data = $this->excel_export_model->fetch_data();

     $excel_row = 2;

     foreach($employee_data as $row)
     {
      $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row, $row->id);
      $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $excel_row, $row->birim);
      $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $excel_row, $row->bolum);
      $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $excel_row, $row->ders_kodu);
      $excel_row++;
     }

     $object_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'Excel5');
     header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Employee Data.xls"');
     $object_writer->save('php://output');
    }
```

after errors there is some data in excel file but corrupted

http://prntscr.com/qfpmok
Can someone help me ?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? PHPExcel is no longer supported and will not work with the current version of PHP (7.4.x).

Comment: I changed the library to PHPSpreadSheet and it worked. Today i saw your answer and checked the php version and it is 7.3.10. I sitll don't know why it didn't work.

Comment: It didn't work because PHPExcel will not work with PHP 7. Simple as that.